# facing in validation the is when i select radio button

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, validation

the main problem is when i select radio button for cash then first field must be mandatory and if i select second button then cheque field must be mendatory...
add HTML code for this program when i submit data the validation not working

```
<form action="add_file.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="form4">
              <table width="400" align="center" cellspacing="10" >

      <tr>
        <td></td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="width:200px;"><label class="label">Purchase Date:</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Purchase_date" id="datepicker" class="button" /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td style="width:200px;"><label class="label">Expanse Head:</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Expanse_head" class="button" /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td style="width::200px"><label class="label">Type of Payment:</label></td>
          <td><input type="radio" name="type" value="cash" />
            cash
            <input type="radio" name="type" value="cheque"/><label>
              cheque</label></td>

        </tr>

      <tr>
        <td style="width:200px;"><label class="label">Expanse Cash:</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="Expanse_cash" class="button" pattern="[0-9]+" required title="Please Enter Digits"/></td>
      </tr>

       <tr>
        <td style="width:200px;"><label class="label">Cheque No</label></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="cno" class="button" /></td>
      </tr>






        <tr style="margin-top:100px;">
        <td><label class="label">Bill</label></td>
        <td><input type="file" name="uploaded_file"  /></td>

      </tr>
       <tr style="margin-top:100px;">
        <td></td>
        <td><input type="submit" value="Save" onclick="return validate(this);" /></td>

      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td></td>

      </tr>


    </table>


          </form>



    <script>
    function validate(){
    if(document.form4.Purchase_date.value==""){alert("Please Enter Date");  return false;}
    if(document.form4.Expanse_head.value==""){alert("Please Enter Expanse Head");   return false;}

    /*if(document.form4.type.value=="1"){
        (document.form4.Expanse_cash.value=="")
            {alert("Please Enter value");   return false;}}
        else(document.form4.type.value=="cheque")
        {
            (document.form4.cno=="");
            {alert ("Please Enter Cheque No "); return false;}}*/

    if(document.form4.uploaded_file.value==""){alert("Please upload file"); return false;}

        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you show your `HTML` code also??? because I cannot understand the names of your controls (objects)!!!

Comment: So you didn't get the answer... I told you show your `HTML` code!!!

Answer (score 0):

rewrite the code, hope this will work !!

if(document.form4.type.value=="**cash**"){

**if**(document.form4.Expanse_cash.value==""){

```
alert("Please Enter value");
return false;
```

}

}

**else if**(document.form4.type.value=="cheque"){

**if**(document.form4.cno.**value**==""){

```
alert ("Please Enter Cheque No "); 
return false;}
```

}

else{

alert("Please select a payment method !!");

}